# Gaussian curvature with Laplacian

Tags: surfaces, curvature, conformal-geometry, laplacian

In a lot of papers and books, I have seen the following expression of Gauss Curvature in $2$-dimensional surfaces with a conformal metric

$$\overline{g} = e^{2u}g$$

$$K - \overline{K} e^{2u} = \Delta u$$

I would like to prove it but I can't see how can i do it. I took the next expression of $K$ in isothermal parameters

$$K = -e^{-2u}\Delta u$$

and I tried to prove it but I did not obtain this expression. How can I prove it?